# How to play image or video file in full screen mode in Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to play video/image file in browser in full screen mode, how can i play them in broswer in full screen mode?

Answer (score 3):

You can use fullscreen mode on an html5 video tag, but it [won't work in IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen) (yet)

Fullscreen API documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Comment: Thanks, my browser is chrome is there any way that same can be used in chrome as well.

Comment: @NitinAggarwal the doc say that there is `element.webkitRequestFullscreen()`

Comment: does this can be called on page load or i have to put a button if move to full screen mode.

Comment: You can call it on page load as far as I know. The browser will ask the user for permission, of course